# How do i create scrolling option like GPay

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image: I have to create a design like this. when the items are scrolling tabs should change to another how can I do the same design? is there any trusted plugins available in flutter?]

I have to create a design like this. when the items are scrolling tabs should change to another how can I do the same design? are there any trusted plugins available in flutter?
I've seen one plugin '*vertical_tab_bar_view: ^0.0.1*' but the popularity is only 68% so I am in doubt?  can anyone get me a solution or proper explanation for the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this?